# Java merge multiple replaceAll - substring one or more occurrence

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Is there a way to combine the following 2 `replaceAll`s into a single `replaceAll`?

```
.replaceAll("(?i)default character set [a-zA-Z0-9]*", "")
.replaceAll("(?i)character set [a-zA-Z0-9]*", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `?` to optionally match `"default "`

```
.replaceAll("(?i)(default )?character set [a-zA-Z0-9]*", "")
```

[**Example**](https://regex101.com/r/v8DmnR/1)